# Cocoa audio issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c

1. I have 2 buttons, 1 turns to the next page and should play a sound at the same time but the sound doesn't seems to be working, I need your help on this please.
2. I have 4 pages and in each page there is a play button that play or stop the audio, but if I press play and press next to the next page, the audio will keep playing, how do I do so that if I press the next button, it will stop the music automatically. 
   Thanks for your help, find below the code.

   ```
   - (IBAction)next {

       // This part plays the next page turn noise
       NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/next.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

       NSError *error;
       audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
       [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
       audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
       [audioPlayer play];

       // This part takes us to the next view
       Rabbana2 *rab = [[Rabbana2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Rabbana2" bundle:nil];
       [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
       [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
       [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];

       [self.view addSubview:rab.view];
       [UIView commitAnimations];

   }

   // This button plays the audio
   - (IBAction)play {

       if(clicked == 0){
           clicked = 1;
           NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rabbana1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

           NSError *error;
           audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
           [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
           audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;


           [audioPlayer play];
           [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sstop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       } 
       else{
           [audioPlayer release];
           clicked = 0;
           [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       } 

   }

   //If user does not do anything by the end of the sound set the button to start
   - (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                           successfully: (BOOL) flag {
       if (flag==YES) {
           clicked = 0;
           [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Shouting for help and then smiling innocuously isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: Also, this is not specific to Xcode. This is a Cocoa question. The IDE that organizes and compiles your project isn't responsible for your coding woes.

Comment: Ok - I accept your comments, apologies if i did offend anyone. Peace!

Answer (score 0):

In your method which handles the page turn, you need to stop the current playing sound by using `[audioPlayer stop]` if it is playing

Comment: @ BoltClock :- I'm not shouting to anyone, I did put it in CAPS to have people attention, end of the story, if you can't help then walk your way.

Comment: @ Coneybeare :- Thanks for your reply, any idea on how I would play the page turn sound please (having already have the play sound which is working ) cheers.

Comment: Use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound. Attacking the people who are telling you how to properly use this site will get you nowhere. It also gives people no reason to help you. End of the story.