# Difficulty playing Audio file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi there I'm trying to play a page turn sound when I click on the "next" button to take me to the next page, but the sound does not come, while when I press the "play" button for the music, it plays the music, can anyone help here please.
Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)next {

    // This part plays the next page turn noise
    NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/next.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [audioPlayer play];

    // This part takes us to the next view
    Rabbana2 *rab = [[Rabbana2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Rabbana2" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:rab.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

// This button plays the audio
- (IBAction)play {

    if(clicked == 0){
        clicked = 1;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rabbana1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;


        [audioPlayer play];
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sstop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } 
    else{
        [audioPlayer release];
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 

}

//If user does not do anything by the end of the sound set the button to start
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: I see nothing glaringly wrong with your code, do you get any warnings, errors, etc? Are you sure that the URL for the source of the sound file is constructed correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa audio issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231346/cocoa-audio-issues)

Comment: I suggest you read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq if you want to get any answers. Duplicated questions will be closed

Comment: I don't get any warning nor errors, it loads the app and when I click on Next it takes me to the next page without playing the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that your audio file is properly encoded.  It is possible your code is executing the playback, but because you might have an audio file improperly encoded it won't play.

Here is a command line conversion to convert a wav file to caf (which iphones love)

afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 in.wav out.caf

Comment: It looks like the "next" sound he is having issues with is a .mp3, what might the conversion look like for that?